# Rails5でLINEログインができません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, line

Rails初心者です。Rails5でLINEログインができません。
実装方法については、以下のサイト通りに進めました。
https://techdatebook.hatenablog.com/entry/rails_line

LINEログインがhttp非対応とのことで、herokuにデプロイしました。

状況：
LINE Loginのリンクをクリックすると[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
という画面になります。

この時のherokuログは以下の通りです。

```
2018-05-04T21:58:03.817089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/users/auth/line" host=frozen-plains-60626.herokuapp.com 
request_id=6326ae36-2a05-4dcd-8d87-aae95c3b872d fwd="118.103.63.152" 
dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=1288 protocol=https
2018-05-04T21:58:03.814586+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05- 
04T21:58:03.814467 #4]  INFO -- : [6326ae36-2a05-4dcd-8d87-aae95c3b872d] 
Started GET "/users/auth/line" for 118.103.63.152 at 2018-05-04 21:58:03 +0000
2018-05-04T21:58:03.814915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05- 
04T21:58:03.814850 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (line) Request phase initiated.
2018-05-04T21:58:04.121453+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-04T21:58:04.121330 #4]  INFO -- : [72f4aa05-a199-4eca-963a-87cb9f430bf8] Started GET "/users/auth/line" for 118.103.63.152 at 2018-05-04 21:58:04 +0000
2018-05-04T21:58:04.121881+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-04T21:58:04.121811 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (line) Request phase initiated.
2018-05-04T21:58:04.124748+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/auth/line" host=frozen-plains-60626.herokuapp.com request_id=72f4aa05-a199-4eca-963a-87cb9f430bf8 fwd="118.103.63.152" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=1288 protocol=https
```

環境：
ruby:2.3.1
rails:5.1.6

何かしらアドバイスをいただけるとありがたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

画面に表示されているように、リクエストを実行するときに`client_id`が
パラメータとして設定できていないようです。
以下のLINEログインのドキュメントを参考に必須となっているパラメータを
全て使用するように変更して試してみてください。

https://developers.line.me/ja/docs/line-login/web/integrate-line-login/